# Elements of $SO(3)$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I can prove that any elemento $A\in SO(3)$ must be the conjugation of:
$$A'=\left(\begin{array}{ccc}
\cos\theta &-\sin\theta &0\\
\sin\theta &\cos\theta &0\\
0&0&1
\end{array}\right)$$
(that is, there exists $P\in O(3)$ s.t. $P^t AP=A'$)

**My question is:** $P$ must be the identity matrix? (and so $A=A'$)?

Comment: Your question is strange: evidently $P$ has not to the identity: it suffices to take $P=\left(\begin{array}{ccc}
1 & 0 & 0\\ 0 &\cos\alpha &-\sin\alpha \\
0 & \sin\alpha  &\cos\alpha  
\end{array}\right)$

Answer (score 1):

No, $P$ need not be the identity matrix. In general, an element $A\in SO(3)$ has the form

$$   
 \left(  \begin{array}{ccc}
\cos\theta \cos\psi & -\cos\phi \sin\psi + \sin\phi \sin\theta \cos\psi &   \sin\phi \sin\psi + \cos\phi \sin\theta \cos\psi \\\
\cos\theta \sin\psi &  \cos\phi \cos\psi + \sin\phi \sin\theta \sin\psi & -\sin\phi \cos\psi + \cos\phi \sin\theta \sin\psi \\\
-\sin\theta             &  \sin\phi \cos\theta                                          &   \cos\phi \cos\theta 
\end{array} 
  \right)  
  $$